# How to convert Double to string in json output

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, double, response

I have an object which is given below:

```
public class Statics {
private Double sum;
private Double avg;
private Double max ;
private Double min ;
private Long count = Long.valueOf(0);//getter and setters and constructrures}
```

and I have a controller which return this object:

```
  @GetMapping("/statistics")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public ResponseEntity<?> getStatics(){

    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(staticService.getStatics());
}
```

and the service implementation is :

```
        private Statics statistics;
        
                public Statics getStatics() {
                if (statistics == null) {
                    Dou
    
    ble Zero =BigDecimal.valueOf(0.00).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).doubleValue();
                statistics = new Statics(Zero, Zero, Zero, Zero, Long.valueOf(0));
            }
            return statistics;
        }
 @Async
    public void statisticAnalysis() {

        DoubleSummaryStatistics stat = TRANSACTION_LIST.stream().mapToDouble(Transaction::getAmount)
                .summaryStatistics();
        statistics = new Statics(BigDecimal.valueOf(stat.getSum()).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).doubleValue(), BigDecimal.valueOf(stat.getAverage()).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).doubleValue(), BigDecimal.valueOf(stat.getMax()).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).doubleValue(), BigDecimal.valueOf(stat.getMin()).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).doubleValue(), stat.getCount());

    }
```

I want my output to be like the expected one in the mage that I will attach below,[ "sum": "100" in double quotation] but it always returns the number without quotations, what should I do?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    public class Statics {
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING)
    private Double sum;
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING)
    private Double avg;
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING)
    private Double max ;
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING)
    private Double min ;
    private Long count = Long.valueOf(0);
}
```

Using this annotation: `@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING)`
Solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

Use `String` instead of `Double` do your calculations on double the convert value to `String.ValueOf(sum)` and set value to your `statistics` POJO.

Convert your POJO like below

```
public class Statics {
private String sum;
private String avg;
private String max;
private String min;
private Long count = Long.valueOf(0);//getter and setters and constructrures
}
```

Comment: I solved my problem, please check the other answer. thank you by the way.

Comment: @Nejatians It will solve your problem I agree but has performance impact on JSON parsing.